# How to wrap a component with styles inside the MuiThemeProvider tag?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating the AppBar using the [component demo](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-demos/app-bar):

The Navbar component:

```
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet('Navbar', {});

function Navbar(props) {

  return (
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography type="title" color="inherit" >Title</Typography>
            <Button color="contrast">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
  );
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

// Now applying the (empty) style:    
const StyledNavbar = withStyles(styleSheet)(Navbar);
```

This works:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div>
            <Navbar />
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

but the following doesn't. Nothing is displayed and no error:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div>
            { StyledNavbar }
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout
```

Can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

**Additional Info:**

I am implementing this in my rails app using this html tag:

```
<div data-react-class="Layout" data-react-props="{}"></div>
```

and letting [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#use-with-webpacker) do its magic.

Comment: try this: `<div>
            <StyledNavbar/>
          </div>`

Comment: @MayankShukla that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render `StyledNavbar` component like this:

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
        <StyledNavbar/>
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

it might be helpful, rendering components like this

```js
import { withStyles, createStyleSheet } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';

<MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
        <StyledNavbar/>
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```